# How would you get the Average Background Color of a Website in Swift?

Tags: swift, web, colors, wkwebview

I am creating an app where I want menu bar to camouflage with the color of a website the user is on. how can I go about doing this is in swift?

Comment: Could you just make the menu bar translucent?

Comment: yes, However the menu is below the web view not above it, and it would stop uses from accessing the bottom part of the webpage, I wanted to really go for a stealthy web browser that camouflages based on the website